# What's the difference between comment and note?

Tags: differences

Please give explanation and sample sentences, thank you guys!

Comment: In what sense? The textual difference is obvious, and the analysis of site functions is out of scope here. We still have *definition* and *connotation*, and perhaps other senses in which they can be different. Which are you after? It can help for you to edit your question to include some background on why the words appear similar (or otherwise) to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A note may contain an opinion.  A comment must contain an opinion.

If I say, "I have zero up votes so far" I'm not commenting.  I'm making note of a fact.  If I say, "Hey, I should have some upvotes by now" I've made a comment that expressed an opinion.  Others may disagree.

Of course you can take note of the existence of an opinion.  Once expressed, its existence is a fact.

> **note**
>
> nōt/Submit
>
> noun
>
> 1. a brief record of facts, topics, or thoughts, written down as an aid to memory.
>
> "I'll make a note in my diary"
>
> synonyms:  record, entry, item, notation, jotting, memorandum, reminder, aide-mémoire; More
>
> 2. a short informal letter or written message.
>
> "I left her a note explaining where I was going"
>
> synonyms:  message, communication, letter, line; More
>
> verb
>
> 1. notice or pay particular attention to (something).
>
> "noting his mother's unusual gaiety"
>
> synonyms:  bear in mind, be mindful of, consider, observe, heed, take notice of, pay attention to, take in
>
> "we will note your suggestion"
>
> 2. record (something) in writing.
>
> "he noted down her address on a piece of paper"
>
> synonyms:  write down, put down, jot down, take down, inscribe, enter, mark, record, register, pencil (in)
>
> "note the date in your diary"
>
> [google: note define](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=note%20define)
>
> **comment**
>
> ˈkäment/
>
> noun
>
> 1. a verbal or written remark expressing an opinion or reaction.
>
> "you asked for comments on the new proposals"
>
> synonyms:  remark, observation, statement, utterance; pronouncement, judgment, reflection, opinion, view; criticism
>
> "their comments on her appearance"
>
> verb
>
> 1. express (an opinion or reaction).
>
> "the review commented that the book was agreeably written"
>
> synonyms:  remark on, speak about, talk about, discuss, mention
>
> "they commented on the food"
>
> remark, observe, reflect, say, state, declare, announce;
>
> interpose, interject
>
> "“It will soon be night,” he commented"
>
> [google: comment define](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=comment+define)